# Delphi: Make the window draggable from a component

Tags: forms, delphi, window, customization, drag

I have a custom form (custom shape and transparency) with no borders (`BorderStyle: bsNone`). It has a background image, a normal TImage Component. It want the form to be draggable from the TImage. Is that possible? I'm using Lazarus 1.2.6 (FPC ver.: 2.6.4).

This is what my custom form looks like on an empty desktop: **[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d75xi.jpg)**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a cross-platform solution:

```
type
TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Image1: TImage; 
    procedure Image1MouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
      Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
    procedure Image1MouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X,
      Y: Integer);
    procedure Image1MouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
      Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);

var PX, PY: Integer; 
    MouseIsDown: Boolean;

procedure TForm1.Image1MouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  if Button = mbLeft then begin
    MouseIsDown := True;
    PX := X;
    PY := Y;
  end;
end; 

procedure TForm1.Image1MouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X,
  Y: Integer);
begin
  if MouseIsDown then begin
    SetBounds(Form1.Left + (X - PX), Form1.Top + (Y - PY), Form1.Width, Form1.Height);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Image1MouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  MouseIsDown:=False;
end;
```

Dragging the TImage will cause the Form to be dragged.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using windows, this is the general way to do what you are asking:

```
  uses
    Windows;

  type
    TForm1 = class(TForm)
    private
      procedure WMNCHitTest(var Msg: TWMNCHitTest); message WM_NCHITTEST;
  end; 

  procedure TForm1.WMNCHitTest(var Msg: TWMNCHitTest);
  begin
    Msg.Result := HTCAPTION
  end;
```